# Localisation practices, how to handle difference between language and region

Tags: web, localization, content-management-system

I'm developing a website that will require different content for different regions.

Different regions also have a preferred language (defaulting to English), but may have multiple.

For example, Taiwan and Hong Kong pages have different content, despite having the same preferred language (Traditional Chinese). Each region may have targeted content, but a lot of the content would overlap with each other and other regions. Furthermore, Hong Kong would also want Hong Kong content to be able to display in English.

As someone new to localisation, do existing l10n libraries typically handle these kinds of cases and demarcate between region and language. Would you have to copy the language specific content multiple times for each region? Or would you just create one language file (or however the language strings are stored) for each language, and different regions just pull relevant content from the same language files depending on what that region needs?

I am likely going to be using a CMS (currently thinking Silverstripe), but I haven't decided yet as I am still figuring out the requirements (including localisation).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting, but very broad question.

I would draw a distinction here between **content** (different pages, sections, menus..) and **translations** (different versions of the content).

In the sense that i18n libraries display translations within a common template - the **locale** (language+region) tends to be one and the same thing. Taking your example, you described three locales: `zh-HK`, `en-HK` and `zh-TW`. (Possibly `en-TW` too, although that wasn't clear).

The question is whether these locales are merely translations - Is it enough to simply create three **versions** of the same bits? If so, a common approach to the overlap factor is **fallback**. i.e. You might allow your zh-TW locale to fall back to the zh-HK in cases where they can be identical.

If that approach works, then check if your chosen CMS supports per-language fallback (as opposed to a single global fallback to English, as is common)

However, if the content differs wildly between regions (totally different pages, menus etc..) then I would say it's typical to run separate instances of your CMS. hk.example.com and tw.example.com both available in whatever language translations you see fit. This will probably prevent sharing of content when it overlaps. That's the case in every CMS I've worked with but perhaps someone else can tell you differently.